# Talking about movies

Tags: словоупотребление, узус

When describing a movie, how does one say "the movie is set in New York, in the early fifties"? Alternatively: "The movie takes place in NY in the early fifties."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Действие фильма происходит в Нью-Йорке в начале пятидесятых.

Comment: I also saw something like (I don't remember the exact words): "сюжет (фильма) разворачивается в Н.Й...." is that a good variant?

Comment: @CocoPop yes, this is good as well.

Comment: @CocoPop, I have never seen "New York" shortened as "Н.Й." in Russian.

Comment: @Vi.: Me neither, I was just saving time, so you just saw it - I did it - BANG! Feel free to use it. You're welcome :)